# Insert compound object into ContentValues

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want to insert an object into a contentValues. the structure of the object is like that:

```
    public class A {
        String x;
        String y;
        object B;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put arbitrary objects into `ContentValues`. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html) for what you can put in `ContentValues`. The only option I see is if you can convert the object to and from a byte array.